# Listing files with Drive API is not returning all files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API (v3) to download and display metadata for all files in a user's drive. Recently I have discovered a problem for some users, where some files are not returned by the `list()` method

Listing of all files is done by the following (simplified) Python code

```
result = self.get_service().files().list().execute()
file_list = result["files"]
while "nextPageToken" in result:
    result = self.get_service().files().list(pageToken=result["nextPageToken"]).execute()
    file_list = file_list + result["files"]
```

For example, one user has a folder "H", which should contain a certain number of files, as seen in the stock Drive web app. After processing the list, I do find an entry corresponding to "H", but no entries that have the id of "H" in their `parents` array.

The permission scope used by the app is full access: 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"

(I've seen some similar questions here and on Google's product forums, but nothing that was more recent than 2014.)

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Request includes trashed files - we can see the 'trashed=True' parameter in other results. I also know it's not a pagination issue - the `nextPageToken` value is always present when expected, and I have seen the output of file_list having a length longer than 1000 - the maximum page size

Comment: I was experiencing something similar with the REST API, having reported it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62402730) with network traces the issue was closed as a duplicate of yours. Although I have since stopped seeing this bug so it might have been fixed. I can't say I'm overly impressed with the feedback on their bug tracker!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks incomplete inasmuch as your call to files.list isn't requesting nextPageToken amongst the result fields. NB This might be being done by the python library (I don't like libraries). Without nextPageToken being correctly handled, your results will be indeterminate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. nextPageToken is included by default in the results if available - I can verify this as we have had resulting `file_list` with sizes over 1000 - the maximum pageSize

Comment: cool. for safety's sake, I'd suggest printing it anyway to be sure.